iOS Radio App: Need to extract and stream audio-only from HLS streams with video content
I'm developing an iOS radio app that plays various HLS streams. The challenge is that some stations broadcast HLS streams containing both audio and video (example: https://svs.itworkscdn.net/smcwatarlive/smcwatar/chunks.m3u8), but I want to:
Extract and play only the audio track
Support AirPlay for audio-only streaming
Minimize data usage by not downloading video content
Technical Details:
iOS 17+
Swift 6
Using AVFoundation for playback
Current implementation uses AVPlayer with AVPlayerItem
Current Code Structure:
class StreamPlayer: ObservableObject { @Published var isPlaying = false private var player: AVPlayer? private var playerItem: AVPlayerItem?

func playStream(url: URL) {
    let asset = AVURLAsset(url: url)
    playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)
    player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
    player?.play()
}


Stream Analysis: When analyzing the video stream using FFmpeg:
CopyInput #0, hls, from 'https://svs.itworkscdn.net/smcwatarlive/smcwatar/chunks.m3u8':
  Stream #0:0: Video: h264, yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 25 fps
  Stream #0:1: Audio: aac, 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp


Attempted Solutions:
Using MobileFFmpeg:
let command = [
    "-i", streamUrl,
    "-vn",
    "-acodec", "aac",
    "-ac", "2",
    "-ar", "44100",
    "-b:a", "128k",
    "-f", "mpegts",
    "udp://127.0.0.1:12345"
].joined(separator: " ")

ffmpegProcess = MobileFFmpeg.execute(command)

I

ssue: While FFmpeg successfully extracts audio, playback through AVPlayer doesn't work reliably.
Tried using HLS output:
let command = [
    "-i", streamUrl,
    "-vn",
    "-acodec", "aac",
    "-ac", "2",
    "-ar", "44100",
    "-b:a", "128k",
    "-f", "hls",
    "-hls_time", "2",
    "-hls_list_size", "3",
    outputUrl.path
]


Issue: Creates temporary files but faces synchronization issues with live streams.

Testing URLs:
Audio+Video: https://svs.itworkscdn.net/smcwatarlive/smcwatar/chunks.m3u8
Audio Only: https://mbcfm-radio.mbc.net/mbcfm-radio.m3u8

Requirements:

Real-time audio extraction from HLS stream
Maintain live streaming capabilities
Full AirPlay support
Minimal data usage (avoid downloading video content)
Handle network interruptions gracefully

Questions:

What's the most efficient way to extract only audio from an HLS stream in real-time?
Is there a way to tell AVPlayer to ignore video tracks completely?
Are there better alternatives to FFmpeg for this specific use case?
What's the recommended approach for handling AirPlay with modified streams?

Any guidance or alternative approaches would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
What I Tried:

Direct AVPlayer Implementation:


Used standard AVPlayer to play HLS stream
Expected it to allow selecting audio-only tracks
Result: Always downloads both video and audio, consuming unnecessary bandwidth



FFmpeg Audio Extraction:

let command = [
    "-i", "https://svs.itworkscdn.net/smcwatarlive/smcwatar/chunks.m3u8",
    "-vn",                    // Remove video
    "-acodec", "aac",        // Audio codec
    "-ac", "2",              // 2 channels
    "-ar", "44100",          // Sample rate
    "-b:a", "128k",          // Bitrate
    "-f", "mpegts",          // Output format
    "udp://127.0.0.1:12345"  // Local stream
]
ffmpegProcess = MobileFFmpeg.execute(command)


Expected: Clean audio stream that AVPlayer could play
Result: FFmpeg extracts audio but AVPlayer can't play the UDP stream


HLS Segmented Approach:

swiftCopylet command = [
    "-i", streamUrl,
    "-vn",
    "-acodec", "aac",
    "-f", "hls",
    "-hls_time", "2",
    "-hls_list_size", "3",
    outputUrl.path
]


Expected: Create local HLS playlist with audio-only segments
Result: Creates files but faces sync issues with live stream

Expected Behavior:

Stream plays audio only
Minimal data usage (no video download)
Working AirPlay support
Real-time playback without delays

Actual Results:

Either downloads full video stream (wasteful)
Or fails to play extracted audio
AirPlay issues with modified streams
Sync problems with live content


Yeah, well your source stream includes both tracks in the same segment file so short of some heroic ranged requests and custom parsing, there's not a lot you can do client-side. Even if you did implement that, you'll end up with a lot of overhead in the request data, and it isn't going to work on AirPlay anyway.  You can do a server-side proxy of course that strips the video track, but you'll have to pay for all that bandwidth. In any case, don't just come here on Stack Overflow with your entire product statement expecting someone to do it for you. Break your problem down into parts.
